# How are we supposed to cancel some hard tasks immediately?

Tags: java, android

How are we supposed to cancel some hard tasks (while it is being executed)?

For example in Android I create `Thread` and I call native method in `run` method

```
public class HardTask extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        // here I call a native method (using JNI, C/C++ function, .so lib)
        // and its execution takes quite a lot of time, 5-40 seconds
        nativeMethod(some parameters);
    }
}
```

What if I need to cancel execution of this method while it is being executed, e.g. before I can use this method again I how to wait until it finishes otherwise if I start another thread and run this method while the first one is still being executed I would get an native error (something like `A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)`) which of course will cause app to crash

It's 2018 and there is no any alternatives to deprecated `Thread.stop()` method

All we can do is to check some boolean `isRunning` after each line of code or in while (`while(isRunning)`) which would just allow you to stop after some line and that line still can be executed about 5-40 seconds and we are just waiting until it finishes...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manage some variable like `isRunning`. All you have to do is put a lock on thread so only one instance can run the thread at a time. In your code you can do this:

```
public void run() {
synchronized(this) {
        // here I call a native method (using JNI, C/C++ function, .so lib)
        // and its execution takes quite a lot of time, 5-40 seconds
        nativeMethod(some parameters);
}
    }
```

Put you code under synchronized block. the code reside in synchronize block can only be executed at a time by one thread. once first thread execute this block other one can start executing this block.

Comment: yes I understand it, but I as said I want to start a new execution immediately and cancel the previous one rather than wait until the previous execution finishes